# Which is the best approacho to analize repeated measures of categorical data?

Tags: r, categorical-data, repeated-measures

I have the results of an experiment done on 60 individuals (n=60). The experiment was divided into four stages and after each one, we did a set of measurements of each individual and we assigned the individual to one of three categories (high, low, medium). The data I want to analyze looks like this

```
individual    stage1    stage2     stage3     stage4
   1          MED        MED        LL        MED
   2          LL         MED        LL        MED
   3          LL         LL         MED       FL
   4          MED      MED          FL        MED
```

I need to analyze the variation of the three categories during the four stages of the experiment. If the data were numeric, the most simple approach would be a repeated measures test. In this case, I have found that [Mixture hidden Markov Models](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seqHMM/vignettes/seqHMM.pdf) or [Generalized Estimating Equations](https://data.library.virginia.edu/getting-started-with-generalized-estimating-equations/#:%7E:text=Generalized%20Estimating%20Equations%2C%20or%20GEE,(ie%2C%20model%20coefficients)) would be good approaches for this kind of data. But I am not sure what would be better in this case.
Any suggestions of what would be the best approach in this case?
Regards

Comment: multivariate ordered probit or logit would be a good starting point.

Comment: I need to evaluate variation in 4 different moments in the examples I have checked [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317944633_Multivariate_Ordered_Logistic_Regression_Models_Dealing_with_the_Model-Building_Strategy) and [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/roprobit.pdf)  they do not consider variation in time. I've edited my question to avoid confusion. I thought it was clear that high, medium, or low were a classification and not an order.  My apologies.

Comment: First of all, it's *always* better to model continuous as opposed to categorical predictors for the simple reason that the former contain more information. If possible, revert to pre-partitioned information. If that's not possible, then log-linear modeling would probably be a good baseline against which to evaluate more complex approaches such as HMM. The late Stephen Feinberg's books *Discrete Multivariate Analysis* and *Analysis of Cross-Classified Categorical Data* are good starts, as is Wicken's *Multiway Contingency Tables Analysis for the Social Sciences*.